# GPU rendering fails with "CUDA error at cuCtxCreate: Invalid device" for gtx 960 but works for gtx 1050ti

Tags: gpu

As the title says, I just installed the 375 version of the drivers from  `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` on ubuntu 16.04 and installed a 1050ti card.

After a reboot everything was working. Then the system offered to apply some updates which IIRC didn't have anything to do with graphics, or blender, and since then when I try to render with the gtx 960 I get

```
CUDA error at cuCtxCreate: Invalid device
```

Rendering with the 1050ti works okay. I tried installing cuda 8.0 with the run file from nvidia's website but the problem remains.

Note that cuda 8.0 says my configuration is unsupported and wants to revert to drivers 367 but this will cause the 1050ti to be ignored.

#### EDIT:

I reverted to the previous situation (`nvidia-367` + `cuda-toolkit` from the repo), and I also tried `nvidia-367` with `cuda-toolkit-8.0` from nvidia (the recommended configuration) and still no joy.

I also tried resetting blender preferences (not during reverted drivers though) and deleting precompiled kernels with no success.

#### EDIT2:

On a clean **ubuntu 16.04** install on the same machine everything works fine, so it's obviously not a bug.

I filed [one](https://developer.blender.org/T50232) however before reaching to that conclusion. As it's a real pain to have to migrate everything to a clean install, I'm reopening this in case somebody has any idea.

Comment: This is probably either a bug with Blender or the graphics drivers. Please report it to the bug tracker.

Comment: It might be, but as it continues to happen both with older drivers and with older blender, I suspect that it's probably a misconfiguration of sorts. I will report it.